# Unexpected behaviour when loading a large file into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, large-files

I am trying to load a large (1.5G) file into pandas but am having some very odd problems. When I load the file, one column seem to have a mixed datatype - some 'str' and some 'float'. eg

> > > sessions.visitor_gwp[2]
> > >       '185511.545011'
> > >
> > > sessions.visitor_gwp[8540709]
> > >       1349514214092.844

The dtype of the Series itself is dtype('O'). The content of the column in the file is a mixture of numeric and alphanumeric data. So I would expect *all* elements to be type 'str'.

This only occurs with some specific combinations of columns (extracting only the relevant column in unix results in a working file) and seems to depend on the order of the rows in the file!

There are 14 columns and 10M rows in the file.

This is the command I am using:
sessions=pandas.read_csv('bigfile.txt', delimiter='\t')

I tried setting comment and quotechar to a character that doesn't appear in the file, like '~'. This doesn't help.

I can work around this by specifying the dtype explicitly but it seems odd that the automatic type detection behaves like this, since I believed (perhaps wrongly) that Series objects should represent elements of a single type.

Thanks,
Martin

pandas.**version**= '0.10.1'
numpy.**version**='1.7.0'

Comment: Could you write a little script to extract the 2nd and 8540709th lines of the file so we can see the text data which is causing the problem? Please post the `repr` of those lines. (That way, any special or hidden characters will be visible.)

Comment: Sorry can't really post the file. But if I extract the two lines the resulting file behaves normally, so I don't think there is anything in the lines themselves. Also changing the order of the lines in the file makes everything work fine.

Comment: @user1483269 It's not clear what your expected output is. If some things are strings and some are numbers then pandas will make the dtype of the Series object, e.g., `Series([1, 'a'])` has a dtype of object. Is the actual data a mixture of types? If so, then that is not a problem. It's not clear what the actual problem is here. One solution is to write a regular expression that matches anything except floating point numbers and run that over the column to see where the funny business is if the problem is that there's weird text somewhere in the column.

Comment: The problem is that numbers seem to be treated differently depending on where they are in the file. The SAME number is treated as both a string AND a number. This leads to unexpected behaviour such as >>>set(a['experiment_name'])
set([580, '580', 104, 'basket-page', 'add-to-bag', 284, '284', '104'])

Comment: submitted issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3866